# Outlook: quick way to add Mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

In Outlook 2003, to add an additional Mailbox, you have to go to:

- Tools
- Email Accounts
- Next
- Change
- More Settings
- Advanced Tab
- Add

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Outlook Profiler does this:
http://goffconcepts.com/products/profiler/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm managing Exchange servers and Outlook 2003-07 and 10 ans supporting 300 users with their Outlook 2003-2007 client and there is no **quicker** way to add an additional mailbox to an Outlook client.

That would be interesting to have a tool to add someone really quick but why make things easy when we can make them complicated. I'm kidding, the way its used to be is kinda easy tho!

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Mail

Takes you to the tools option in outlook I believe, don't know if it's any faster though.

Answer (score -1):

In Outlook 2003?  Not without 3rd party tools.  The solution is to upgrade to Outlook 2007+ and Exchange 2007+, which offer the feature of auto-configuring profiles.

Comment: Auto configuration is not auto management. Entirely different subject being discussed here. Exchange 2007 can not read your mind and add mailboxes or pst files.